# Adding 'x' hours, 'x' minutes and 'x' seconds to DateTime (PHP)

Tags: php

The I have a certain timestamp and want to add an `'x' hours`, `'x' minutes` and `'x' seconds` to it.

I tried it like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); 
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', number_format(microtime(true), 6, '.', ''));
$now = $now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');

echo '<br> Localized: '.$now;

echo '<br> Time1: '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours +5 minutes +4 seconds', $now));

echo '<br> Time2: '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+0 hours +5 minutes +4 seconds', $now));
```

---

```
Localized: 2018-06-12 10:51:32.166452

Time1: 1970-01-01 03:38:42
Time2: 1970-01-01 00:38:42
```

But the result is incorrect like that... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `strtotime()` expects an integer as second parameter, not a DateTime instance.

Comment: @Dormilich, okay so how would I accomplish adding extra hours, minutes and seconds to DateTime?

Comment: put a separate `localized` variable, then reuse `$now` as `$now->format('U')` on the `strtotime` function, if you have turned on php errors, you would have noticed wrong function usage error firsthand

Comment: Either by using http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php or http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change `DateTime` object by [add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) method. It takes [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object. But it changes object if you want to create new objects you should use [DateTimeImmutable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php)

```
$now->add(new DateInterval('PT3H5M4S'));
```

`P` - required prefix means "Period"

`T` - means "Time" it must be present before time period because date and time periods have equals char `M`

In this case:

- `3H` - 3 hours
- `5M` - 5 minutes
- `4S` - 4 seconds

Full period example can be like this `new DateInterval('P1Y2M5DT3H5M4S')` and will equals to period 1 year 2 months 5 days 3 hours 5 minutes and 4 seconds.

Comment: What does PT mean in this case?

Comment: you can omit zero value

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko The time that comes from the other source sometimes has 0 for hours or seconds. And I dont want to do any additional processing.

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko I get this error `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add()`.

Comment: @Borsn you called this method after assigning `$now` `format` method result?

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko Yes. But I corrected. Will something like this be feasible: `0Y0M59D9H1M4S`? Theres two `M's` repeating, don't know the designation for Month. Cause this is the time I get from the other source.

Comment: I updated answer. You should add `T` delimiter between date and time periods and result will `0Y0M59DT9H1M4S`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [DateTime.modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php).

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); 

$now = new DateTime();
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

$date1 = clone $now;
$date1->modify('+3hours +5minutes +4seconds');

$date2 = clone $now; 
$date2->modify('+0hours +5minutes +4seconds');

echo '<pre>' . var_export($now, true) . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' . var_export($date1, true) . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' . var_export($date2, true) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert you `$now` into `strtotime()`

```
echo '<br> Time1: '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours +5 minutes +4 seconds', strtotime($now)));

echo '<br> Time2: '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+0 hours +5 minutes +4 seconds', strtotime($now)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Second parameter in `strtotime` function should be integer. So convert `$now` to Unix timestamp. Read about [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

This worked well:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', number_format(microtime(true), 6, '.', ''));
$now = $now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');



echo '<br> Localized: ' . $now;

$time = strtotime($now);

echo '<br> Time1: ' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours +5 minutes +4 seconds', $time));

echo '<br> Time2: ' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+0 hours +5 minutes +4 seconds', $time));
```